# Combine mouse-events in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, events, dom

I am trying to build a Paint-like web application using javascript. The user is supposed to be able to "draw" shapes with the mouse over a grid of pixels.
How can i get this working using DOM eventlisteners?

with this line the user is able to set single pixels one by one:

```
td.addEventlistener("click", setpixel);
```

So i guess I have to combine mousedown and mouseover in one eventlistener. Is that possible?

Comment: It all depends on how you code it....

Comment: it depends on a lots of things your aren´t telling. Do you want the user hold their mouse and paint some "pixels" at mouse position? Because your are talking about shapes and shapes are more complex than simulated pixels in the DOM. Can´t you use Canvas? here is a nice example of that http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-drawing-app/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't combine event listeners, per se. But you **can** use multiple listeners to track the state of the cursor.

```
var mouseIsDown = false
el.addEventListener('mousedown', function(){mouseIsDown = true})
el.addEventListener('mouseup', function(){mouseIsDown = false})
```

Then you will need to decide what to do when the mouse is moving.

```
el.addEventListener('mousemove', function(){
    if(mouseIsDown){
        // implement drawing logic here
    }
})
```